# Plotly.js not working with SSR Angular application

Tags: angular, angular7, plotly, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to build an Angular app with SSR, but I ran into problems with plotly.js. 
Here is the error I get:

> C:\Users\x\Desktop\Angularapp\ngseo\dist\server.js:351783
>
> ```
>     var style = document.getElementById(id);
>                 ^
> ```
>
> ReferenceError: document is not defined

Do you have any idea how to solve this error?

Comment: which angular are you using Agularjs or Angular 2? If you are using angular 2 then this will not work .you have to use  @ViewChild('myDiv') myDiv: ElementRef;

Comment: I'm using Angular 7

Comment: I've changed [tag:angularJs] to [tag:angular7] as you commented it -HTH ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this in Angular 7

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, ViewChild,Renderer2,OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef) {}
  id='';
  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.el.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('mydiv')[0];
     console.log(this.id);
  }
}

<p class="mydiv"> 
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
```